# Fabric JS Touch Events

Tags: fabricjs, phonegap

I'm working with Fabric js inside a Phonegap application and although the touch events work, the handles are very hard to catch and use. Specifically the rotate and resize handles. If you touch them 90% of the time they just disappear. I tired fingers and styles. Same result. Confirmed the same behavior on ipad pro and my Galaxy note 4. I'm copy/pasting the same demo from their site:

http://fabricjs.com/touch-events

Has anyone experienced this? How can I make those handles easier to touch?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. All I needed to do was increase the size of the handles. It's a property passed to each object type you make.